# Android - Convert JPG to PNG with background transparency

Tags: java, android, image, png

I need to take a JPG file and convert it in PNG format in order to add transparency like i'm erasing the image in some parts of it, but I can't make out how to do that, every time i try to manipulate the image, where i add transparency I only see black and not the background image I put, so I think that just converting it won't add the transparent background.
I'm doing that:

```
String cacheDir = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
//create output stream
OutputStream outputStream = null;
//create file
File file = new File(cacheDir, "img.png");
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap2.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, outputStream);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

Then where I touch I do that in order to "erase the image":

```
pTouch = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);         
pTouch.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_OUT)); 
pTouch.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
c2.drawCircle(X, Y, 35, pTouch);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Converting a black background from Jpeg to PNG is going to produce a black background PNG as you should expect. I dont see any code adding transparency, only conversion. Look into `setColorFilter`. You could probably change a single colour to clear.

Comment: You are right, Now I update the question.